# Watching NodeJS Clusters For Exit

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around having a node.js process (something asynchronously) run but still triggering an 'exit' state so I can do more when CPU-crunching is complete.

For example, I've got a Google Places crawler that efficiently distributes http requests across all available CPUs.

```
} else if (cluster.isWorker) {
//  Code to run if we're in a worker process

// Send the object we created above from variables so they're available to the workers
process.on('message', function(clusterDivisionObject) {
    var tempArray;

    // Send the chunk of array appropriate for this cluster to process, then request it's place details
    tempArray = clusterDivisionObject.placeIdArray.splice(((cluster.worker.id * clusterDivisionObject.clusterDivision) - clusterDivisionObject.clusterDivision), clusterDivisionObject.clusterDivision);
    tempArray.forEach(function(arrayItem, index, array){
      request({url: config.detailsRequestURI + '?key=' + config.apiKey + '&placeid=' + arrayItem, headers: config.headers}, detailsRequest);
    });
});
}
```

The real issue here is the last line where I sent an asynchronous `request()` statement.  The code executes correctly but once I hit the callback (`detailsRequest`) to do something (in this case, write to a json file) I don't have any control for exiting the process.  My callback function:

```
function detailsRequest(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var detailsBody = JSON.parse(body);
        ...
    }
}
```

...Has no awareness as to what process is running it or how many iterations it has made (to trigger an exit after the entire `tempArray` is exhausted).  So, assuming that one cluster is running `request()` for `tempArray` of x length, how can I trigger `process.exit(0)` when that `tempArray.forEach(){}` has completed?

I've tried calling a process.exit(0) directly after `tempArray.forEach(){}` but the process will die before `request()` is even ran.  **Is there any efficient way I can watch a process better to call it's exit or am I really trying to tackle a problem that can't exist since `request()` is async and could be called or not called in any order?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need async flow control. You don't want your process exiting until all requests complete. Instead, you're asking node send out all these requests and then exit the process. Checkout [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) or some other flow control library. But you need something like this:

```
var tempArray;
var counter = 0;

tempArray = []; // same as above

// Without asyncjs
tempArray.forEach(function(arrayItem, index, array){
  request({url: config.detailsRequestURI + '?key=' + config.apiKey +'&placeid=' + arrayItem, headers: config.headers}, detailsRequest);
});

function detailsRequest(){ 
 // increment counter and handle response
 // this callback gets called N times.
 counter +=1;
 if(counter >= tempArray.length){ process.exit(0); }
}


//With async.js:

async.map(tempArray, sendRequestFunc, function finalDone(err, results){ 
  // here you can check results array which has response
  // and then exit
  process.exit(0);
}); 

function sendRequestFunc(el, done){ 
  // done callback as per async docs
  // done must be invoked here or the final callback is never triggered 
  request({url:'same as above'}, done)
}
```

Keep in mind that you may need to add additional checks for errors or bad responses and handle those accordingly.

The done callback within the sendRequestFunc is only invoked when the request returns a response or error (async) and the last async callback 'finalDone' is invoked only when all the responses have returned.

Comment: Makes sense enough, but it doesn't quite work right when I'm running multiple clusters at once.  Is there some other way I can scope this out so that the arrays stay straight?

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a gist showing some more of your master/worker code. I'm not sure what you mean when you say 'arrays stay straight'. Could you clarify?

Comment: Here's what I was working with, just in case: https://gist.github.com/ShawnStrickland/04bf64352ce35dca660d

Comment: @ShawnStrickland let me know if that helps, otherwise I'll comment on gist

Comment: I think this is a limitation of the request module since it HAS to be asynchronous. I think I'll refactor my code to utilize multiple concurrent processes on a stored array so I can utilize multi-core performance but still be able to easily destroy processes as I go so nothing is left hanging.

Comment: @ShawnStrickland checkout your gist, I'm not sure you need cluster, nodejs is built for i/o and it appears all you need is to move data around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69868/discussion-between-yousef-and-shawn-strickland).